# load correct store & force to https

Tags: multistore, redirect, htaccess, https

I load stores with htaacess rules like below:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*domain\.pl [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:storepl]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .*domain\.pl [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [E=MAGE_RUN_TYPE:website]
```

How to update above rule to exchange all user `http` URL's automatically to `https` ?
 I added `https` prefix to unsecure Magento base URL and it works but I'm not pretty sure if its the best option ?

Could somebody help with that rule to force `https` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to direct all your visitors to secure urls, you need to go to `System > Configuration > Web > Unsecure`.

There, you can set a URL with `https` in "Base URL" option. It should work without making changes to your `.htaccess` file.

Comment: That's what I did :) but I thought htaacess will be better